# What does a static lifetime of a Fn closure type mean?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

The following error goes away if I do as rustc tells me to, and change the bound to

`where F: Fn() -> () + 'static`

```rust
pub struct Struct(Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>);
pub fn example<F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> ()
{
    Struct(Box::new(|| ())); // ok
    Struct(Box::new(f)); // error: The parameter type `F` may not live long eneough
                         // help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound: `F: 'static`
}
```

However, I just don't understand what 'static means here. It doesn't seem to mean that the *closure itself* lives forever.

At least, it doesn't seem like the closure lives forever. If I have the closure own some data, that data gets dropped at some point, which makes me suspect the closure is dropped:

```rust
pub struct Struct(Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DropMe;
impl Drop for DropMe {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropped");
    }
}

/// prints:
///     "got DropMe"
///     "got DropMe"
///     "dropped"
///     "end of program"
pub fn main() {
    let d = DropMe;
    example(move || {
        println!("got {:?}", d);
    });
    println!("end of program")
}

pub fn example<F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> () + 'static
{
    let s = Struct(Box::new(f));
    s.0();
    s.0();
}
```

Is `'static` an upper bound on the lifetime of the closure rather than a lower bound? `'static` makes sense as an upper bound, then `example` would be saying "give me a function that I can hold on to as long as I want", which in practice can be less than the `'static` lifetime.

How can I tell when `+ 'lifetime` adds `'lifetime` as an upper bound vs. a lower bound?
The Rustonomicon chapter on [subtyping+variance](https://ngolin.github.io/book/rust-nomicon/subtyping.html) doesn't seem to cover this, and I couldn't find the information I was looking for in the Rust Book or Rust Reference.

Answer (score 6):

`T: 'a` isn't a constraint on the lifetime of *instances* of `T`, but of *things that `T` borrows* (if any): that is, *all borrows in* `T` must outlive `'a`.

Thus `F: Trait + 'static` requires that any borrows in `F` be for `'static` lifetime (or longer, which doesn't exist), regardless that `Trait` in this case is `Fn() -> ()`.

In your case, the closure takes ownership of `d` (and borrows the `&'static str` literal); hence it satisfies `F: 'static`.  But if instead of `move || ...` the closure merely borrowed `d` with `|| ...`, then it would not be able to satisfy `'static` (as the lifetime of the borrow of `d` cannot exceed the scope of the call to `main`).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `'static` is an upper bound.

In fact, *all* lifetimes constraints are upper bounds. *For the callee* (that is, whom uses the lifetime).

*For the caller* (i.e. the provider of the lifetime), on the other hand, they're usually lower bounds: give me something that lives at least as `'static` (of course, nothing lives more than `'static`, so it actually means "give me something `'static`". But it does matter when talking about other lifetimes).

Variance is about changing the *caller's* respect regarding the lifetime: whether it can pass a longer lifetime (**covariance**, i.e. a *lower bound*), a shorter lifetime (**contravariance**, i.e. an *upper bound*), or only exactly this lifetime (**invariance**).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm not sure the "for the caller" part is correct.

In my second example, caller is `main` and callee is `example`. `example` asks for an arg with a `'static` lifetime. You wrote that, from the caller's POV, the lifetime is a lower bound. If that's the case, then the second example shouldn't compile, but it does. `f`'s lifetime ends before the static lifetime: the closure is `drop`ed before "end of program" is printed.
What I think is happening is that `'static` is an upper bound. The compiler picks a lifetime that ends just before `println!("end of program")`.

Comment: From `main()`'s POV, the closure is `'static`: because you move the `DropMe` into it, it controls it, meaning it'll drop when the closure will. The closure does not hold any reference to the outside. `example()` _can_ drop it before, like I said: for the callee, this is a an upper bound.

Answer (score 3):

The 'static variant is not obligatory. It seems like it's just what compiler proposes by default.
The two edits below should hopefully illustrate the capture of lifetime of variables from environment.

```rust
//rustc 1.62.1 (e092d0b6b)
pub struct Struct<'a>(Box<dyn Fn() -> () + 'a>);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DropMe;
impl Drop for DropMe {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropped");
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let d = DropMe;
    let x = 43;

    example(move || {
        println!("got {:?} {:?}", d, &x);
    });
    println!("end of program")
}

pub fn example<'env_borrow, F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> () + 'env_borrow
{
    let s = Struct(Box::new(f));
    s.0();
    s.0();
    // drop(s);
    println!("end of higher bound func");
}
```

```rust
// rustc 1.62.1 (e092d0b6b)
pub struct Struct<'a>(Box<dyn FnMut() -> () + 'a>);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DropMe;
impl Drop for DropMe {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropped");
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let d = DropMe;
    let mut x = 43;
    let y = &mut x;

    let closure_boxed = example(move || {
        println!("got {:?} , *&mut x = {:?}", d, y);
        *y += 1;
    });

    // drop(x);
    // ^ ERROR: try uncomment
    drop(closure_boxed);
    // ^ ERROR: try comment
    println!("x is now {}", x);
    println!("end of program")
}

pub fn example<'env_borrow, F>(f: F) -> Struct<'env_borrow>
where
    F: FnMut() -> () + 'env_borrow
{
    let mut s = Struct(Box::new(f));
    s.0();
    s.0();
    s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that `Struct` has no generic lifetime parameters, which means the lifetime of one of its instances has no name. The function an instance of `Struct` boxes (obviously) has to live as long as the instance, but the only way to guarantee that to the compiler is to give it a named lifetime. But because `Struct` has no lifetime parameters, the only named lifetime that is guaranteed to last sufficient long is `'static`.

To fix this, you can give `Struct` a generic lifetime parameter and then constrain the boxed function to also only live that long.

```rust
pub struct Struct<'a>(Box<dyn 'a + Fn() -> ()>);
pub fn example<F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn() -> (),
{
    Struct(Box::new(|| ())); // ok
    Struct(Box::new(f)); // also ok; 'a will be inferred from the lifetime of f
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you may have misunderstood my question. There's no issue to solve with different code: as I explained, I did what rustc told me to do and the compiler error went away. What I was looking for was a better understanding of what 'static means here.